# why is E(xx') the var-covar matrix in regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance

In regression people often refer to the $X'X$ term as the estimate of $E(xx')$ which makes sense by the law of large numbers. However, people also refer to $E(xx')$ as the covariance matrix of $x$ which only seems to make sense if $E(x)=0$. Why does it makes sense if the $x$'s are not demeaned?

Comment: In these situations they probably do assume that the x's have been demeaned. This is a sometimes unstated assumption.

Comment: What does LNN mean?

Comment: LLN: Law of Large Numbers?

Comment: yes, LLN is law of large numbers

Comment: I edited in the full name.  It's bad practice to use abbreviations like that, I truly did not have any idea what you were referring to, and it't frustrating to try to imaging all the concepts I know that may be abbreviated in that way.